# Fail to change directory (shell command) in jupyternotebook (or jupyterlab session)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I can run shell commands from an open jupyterlab (or jupyternotebook) session with an exclamation mark preprended to the shell command, as follows:

```
!mkdir /new_folder
```

This, as well as other commands such as `ls` and `pwd` work, though if I try to **change directory** with `cd`, as shown below

```
!cd /path/to/mydir
```

this does not work and I have noticed that the current working directory will always be the one where my jupyter notebook (.ipynb) is saved.

It is also odd that if I do:

```
!cd /path/to/mydir && pwd
```

I will get `/path/to/mydir` printed out, though if, on the cell below I do

`!pwd`

I will get the current directory where my jupyternotebook is saved i.e. apparently I eventually cannot change the working directory with `!cd` in a jupyternotebook.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use `!cd` to navigate the filesystem from Jupyter notebook. The reason is that shell commands (preceding with `!` symbol) in Jupyter notebook's code cells are executed in a temporary subshell. If you'd like to change the working directory, you can use the `%cd` magic command:

```
!pwd
/d/swatchai_works/tutorial/jupyter

%cd ..
/d/swatchai_works/tutorial

!pwd
/d/swatchai_works/tutorial

%cd jupyter
/d/swatchai_works/tutorial/jupyter
```

**Edit**
Using magic command %cd to change working directory can cause problems to other code running on the jupyter notebook that rely on the directory at the startup of the notebook.

Using chaining bash commands with "&&" operator(s) may be better choice if you dont want to change the current working directory at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing bash scripts in Jupyter (i.e., don't have any Python code). You may consider using the [bash kernel](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel). Unlike using the typical Python kernel, this one keeps everything in the same session, meaning doing `cd dir` will be persistent across cells.

I use Jupyter to write tutorials for my open-source projects, and some of them are mainly command-line interfaces, so using the bash kernel simplifies things a lot: I no longer have to use the `%%bash` magic on each cell, the outputs are updated in real-time (when using `%%bash` then only show up when the command finishes), and I no longer have the cryptic traceback that is thrown when a command fails.